# Django: save() method for ModelForm is not updating the database

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having a problem with saving and updating a value to my database.

View:

```
def code_prof_edit(request, ampCode):
    user_code = get_object_or_404(CodeUser, pk=ampCode)
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = CodeUserForm(request.POST, instance=user_code)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/codes/' + user_code.ampCode)
    else:
        form = CodeUserForm(instance=user_code)
        return render_to_response('edit_code_user.html', {'user_code':user_code, 'form':form})
```

Relevant template form tag:

```
<form action="." method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Using the post method, the form correctly renders in the browser with all of the original values pre-populated, but if I change the values and click submit, none of the changes are made. Everything seems to work correctly in that the user is redirected to the correct page which means the save must have been called, but the info typed isn't being saved.  Any and all help would be appreciated.

Edit entire view function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from codeuser.models import CodeUser
from codeuser.forms import CodeUserForm
import pdb

def code_prof_edit(request, ampCode):
    user_code = get_object_or_404(CodeUser, pk=ampCode)
    if request.method =='POST':
        pdb.set_trace()
        form = CodeUserForm(request.POST, instance=user_code)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/codes/' + user_code.ampCode)
        else:
            return render_to_response('home.html')
    else:
        form = CodeUserForm(instance=user_code)
        return render_to_response('edit_code_user.html', {'user_code':user_code, 'form':form})
```

Edit:  Figured it out.  In the html form tag, the action attribute was incorrect.  "." wasn't working, I needed "./edit" to get the correct result. Also, excluding that attribute all together worked perfectly too.

Comment: You should get a NameError `form` is undefined. You should be calling save on `new_info` -- are you doing that? `new_info.save()`

Comment: @Yuji. That was an old file. New_info should be form and the error I get is with that.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? Can we be sure `form.save()` is being called? It can look like your view would do a redirect even if `not form.is_valid()` - it's ambiguous with the spacing. I'm also assuming you haven't overridden the ModelForm `save()` either.

Comment: @Yuji.  Indentations fixed.  The other weird thing is that if I leave an entry field blank, I don't get yelled at, which I was under the impression was supposed to happen.

Comment: what happens when `form.is_valid()` is `False`? Is there a render function below in that view of yours? Have you used pdb before? I'd put in `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right after the `form.save()` line to ensure 1: `form.save()` is being called, 2: that `form.save()` returns the updated instance of your model. Yes, your form should complain if you have a required field left blank - your form must be getting overriden somewhere.. It would help to see the entire view function instead of guessing / assuming. Right now, your code would poop out on an invalid form and return nothing.

Comment: @Yuji  I've put an else statement with different ending page after is_valid() before and I just did it again and it sent me to the page indicating that form.save() was called.  Using pdb (which I didn't know about so thank you for introducing it to me), I first put a trace at the beginning of the function and it went through all of the code until it rendered the page correctly the first time. Then I put a trace just after the if request.method==Post line and that never got called like it should have. Am I right in saying that the view function will get called again after I click submit?

Comment: `request.method == 'POST'` is pretty much bullet proof and should have triggered your trace if you placed it after that and you posted. Can you please post your entire view function? It's tough to guess how your view works. I will literally run your code on my machine.

Comment: @Yuji  I posted the entire view function with headers and such. If you need more or anything more of the code let me know.  Couple more things, could the problem be with the html? Meaning that I didn't define the submit button to actually submit the forms when clicked?  Also, when running the server, after I click the submit button and It takes me back to the correct page, it shows this:[25/May/2011 18:54:42] "POST /codes/AAAAAA/ HTTP/1.1" 200 301
which I can only assume it means the post went through.  Or maybe not.

Comment: @Yuji. I actually just figured it out. The problem was with the form tag where action="." should have been action="./edit".  Apparently it was sending the post to the wrong view. I actually figured this out from putting a pdb call in the other view. Anyway would you happen to know why I needed the extra part on the action attribute? I was under the impression since the template was for that view it would send to that view again.  Either way thank you so much for trying to help. People like me just trying to learn really appreciate the help from people like you.

Comment: Hey fantastic that you figured it out! (post an answer to your own question and accept that answer) If the URL serving the edit page is `/edit`, then `action="."` should post to the same URL. I've run into one situation where action="." was behaving oddly, in which case leave it blank or remove the attribute altogether to post to the current page.

Comment: @grassclip  If the base URL doesn't end in a `/`, it looks like a "file" rather than a "directory" to the client. In that case, a relative URL like `.` will refer to the enclosing "directory," stripping off the last element of the path (`edit`). Either way, I would use a `{% url %}` template tag pointing to your current view instead of hardcoding the action attribute.